# RecyclerView updates only on scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with a `RecyclerView` with the adapter:

```
public class SimpleRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder> {

  protected List<JSONObject> data = new ArrayList<>();

  public List<JSONObject> getData() { return data; }
}
```

I update it's adapter like:

```
public void udpdateFromJson( JSONObject payload ) {
  JSONArray msgs = payload.optJSONArray( "messages" );
  for( int ix = 0; null != msgs && ix < msgs.length(); ix++ ){
    JSONObject o = msgs.optJSONObject( ix );
    if( loadingMore ) adapter.getData().add( 1 + ix, o );
    else adapter.getData().add( o );
  }

  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  recyclerView.invalidate();
}
```

The problem is, that I get to see the new item only when I touch or scroll the view.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

to fix the problem I replaced the lines

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.invalidate();
```

with

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted( loadingMore ? 1 : 0, msgs.length() );
```

and it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try specifying the position of the item inserted or removed instead of **`notifyDataSetChanged();`**. you can use

```
notifyItemInserted(int pos);
notifyItemRangeChanged(int start, int end);`
```

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged` from background thread.

Simply (and ugly) fix you can do is to use:

```
recyclerView.post(new Runnable(){ @Override public void run(){ adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } });
```

If `notifyDataSetChanged` is called correctly from main thread then the list is updated without touching it.

Comment: Very Good observation and fine abservation.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is use [Realm Adapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters). Thant will manage your scroll view position based on insert/update/delete automatically. There is no flickering effects. Drawback is you have extend Object as Realm Object.

Answer (score -1):

As the question is already answered you can use one more line to scroll to the last position of your recyclerView using:

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(msgs.length()-1)
```